# What do you call the player who is in charge of making strategies on Counter Strike?

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-source

What do you call the player in charge of making strategies in order to help his team win the match?

In France we call him "Strateur", what would the equivalent be in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strat caller is the most widely used term.

Answer (score 1):

igl (in-game leader) or caller